# In Lyx, align text inside a float caption

Tags: captions, lyx, align, legend

I'm trying to align a legend inside a table caption, so that the colons are vertically aligned.
I can do it with the align ambient outside of the caption, but if I use the same code inside the caption the pdf won't compile (I use LuaTeX to compile).
I'm using the package caption.

EDIT: i want something like this:

[image: desired output]

for which i've written this code:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a : {} & the~first~letter~of~the~alphabet \\
b : {} & the~second~one \\
and : {} & so~on
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

There might be a more elegant way... but i don't know it.

Anyway, I can't do it inside the caption, that's why i'm stuck.

Comment: That's almost exactly what my answer gives you, what is wrong with it? Is there anything there written in math mode, should for example the first column be in math mode? Ok, the first column is right aligned, so you can change the `l` before `@{: }` to `r`.

Comment: I didn't try your first answer. My question wasn't very clear indeed, so the first thing i did when i checked if there were any answers was to add the details.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. It is not important, but is it possible to remove the indentation, so that if the first coloumn is left aligned, it is at the very edge of the caption (in line with the rest of the text)?

Comment: Sure, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to write some code in an ERT, you can add a table within the caption. Note however that this requires you to add a short title for the caption.

So, add an ERT within the caption with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or Insert --> TeX code), and write the `tabular` in this. There is a small amount of whitespace at the beginning of a table cell, you can remove this by adding `@{}` before the first column specifier.

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{ : }l}
a & first letter of alphabet \\
b & the second one \\
and & so on
\end{tabular}
```

Then right click the caption "title" (where it says e.g. *Table 1*) and click *Insert short title*. What you write here ends up in the list of tables/figures. Note that this is required, without the short title you get errors.

[image]