# Figure with more than one image in Lyx

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, lyx

I have a Figure with 3 images inside (a) (b) and (c) when I want to write the description of each image in the figure this description is not so well aligned I mean I would like to see something like this:

> ```
> Figure 2  (a) Image corresponding to...
>
>           (b) Image corresponding to...
>
>           (c) Image corresponding to...
> ```

Everything aligned in the center just like in the other figures.

But instead of that I am having.

> Figure 2 (a) Image corresponding to... (b) Image corresponding
>   to...(c) Image corresponding to...

I do not know if I was clear enough but I would appreciate any answer

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The LyX way is not put 3 images inside a figure, but 3 figures with 1 image each. LyX automatically convert  the nested figures to `\subfloats` whit  subcaptions that are automatically labelled as (a), (b), (c) ... and well placed, so you don't need the main caption to describe the each image.

Comment: Are you after something similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131059/in-lyx-align-text-inside-a-float-caption/131061#131061?

Comment: Torbjørn T. Thanks a lot man, that was exactly what I was looking for. It was very useful.